# How many degree n b-splines are there if m knots?

Tags: r, splines

I read in this [course material on b-splines](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-property.html) that:

> number of b-splines = number of knots - degree of b-splines - 1

But when I run `bs(speed, knots=c(14, 20), degree=2)` in R, 4 b-splines are created. According to the above formula, there should be -1 b-splines, which obviously makes no sense. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You might do better on an R site as this is in danger of being closed as off-topic here. The documentation for bs is worth re-reading before you post elsewhere.

Comment: I think this is a borderline case - are you asking about why R does what it does (that would be off-topic, I think) or about the formula for number of b splines (that would be on-topic).

Comment: I guess I am really asking why R does what it does? So would this question be better on Stack Overflow?